# no match for ‘operator<’

Tags: c++, operators

This is probably a very quick fix, but I'm having trouble figuring out why I'm getting an error.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    srand ( time(NULL) );
    double randomNumber = (double)(rand() % 100) / 100;

    string numCars;

    cout << "\nPlease enter the number of cars going through the intersection:" << endl;
    cout << "->";
    getline (cin, numCars);

    for(double i=0; i<numCars; i++){
        cout << randomNumber << endl;
    }

}
```

The error is:

```
 traffic.cpp:80: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘i < numCars’
```

Comment: You can't compare strings and integers. You'll have to convert one. I presume you're doing some checking on the input, which is why it's a string, but if you're not, just start with an int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numCars` is a string. It should have integer type (char, short, int, long)

Comment: Just an added detail: the variable i should most likely be an int as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare a `string` to a numeric value. Read the user input into an `unsigned int`. Change your code to:

```
unsigned int numCars;
if( !(cin >> numCars) ) {
  // invalid user input, handle it
}

for( unsigned int i = 0 ; i < numCars; ++i ) {
  // ...
}
```

I also changed the data type of `i` from `double` to `unsigned int`. There's no reason to use a floating point number unless somehow a fractional number of cars can pass through that intersection.

Answer (score 0):

you can't compare string with integer or you have to define operator for this. Should `numCars` be integer?